# Why is the tension in a pendulum string highest when it is at the mean position?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, free-body-diagram, oscillators, string

Why does the string of a pendulum have max tension when it is at the mean position?

Answer (score 2):

The tension has two jobs: cancel out the part of the gravitational force pointing along the rope, and additionally provide the centripetal force. The first is clearly maximized when the string is vertical. The second is also maximized when the string is vertical, because the mass is lowest and hence moving fastest at that point. So the highest tension occurs when the string is vertical, which is the mean position.